# I want to make a filter by category in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, filter

[Image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmrQK.jpg)

I want to make filter like this, please suggest me any doc or reference or if possible provide me the code in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

the filter typicaly is implemented on the back-end like:

```
https://yourapi/product/filter/id
```

to help you what type of back-end are you using ?

Comment: Hey Marco, thanx for reaching me out here I am sharing with you my question link hope you will sort out my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981058/i-want-to-make-an-e-commerce-filter-by-category-in-angular

Comment: i see but the answer is the same, you don't have to do the filters localy (angular) but on the api, you'll waste a lot of time doing this